# What are the viewing prerequisites for Thor: Ragnarok?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war, thor-ragnarok

I have yet to see *Captain America: Civil War* or *Spider-Man: Homecoming*. Do I need to see both of these, one of them, or neither before watching *Thor: Ragnarok*?

Comment: Nope. But you might want to check out *Thor: The Dark World*, *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, and *Doctor Strange*.

Comment: Even Doctor Strange isn't necessary, it isn't referenced at all, and doesn't add to your understanding or enjoyment of Thor: Ragnarok.

Comment: @JDoe I disagree. The premise of the beginning of the movie references the search for the `Infinity Stones`, one of which happens to be hanging around the neck of Dr. Strange and used to great effect in the `Doctor Strange` movie.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. From what I can remember neither *Captain America: Civil War* or *Spider-Man: Homecoming* are directly referenced. *Thor: Ragnarok* takes place around the same time as both of those movies. Besides, the main characters have been away from Earth since Age of Ulron (which took place before both of those movies).

It is helpful to have seen *Thor*, *Thor: The Dark World*, and *Avengers: Age of Ultron* for some background on what happened before this movie started. It is nice (but by no means necessary) to see *The Avengers* and *Doctor Strange* as well.